# typescript in ASPNET core 2 with angular - acces html document

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript, .net-core

I've searched a while for this but I feel like this is one of the basics so no one bothers to explain it anymore...

Here's my problem.

I'm writing a component in TypeScript, which is part of an ASPNET core 2 and angular project.

TS file :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'clients',
    templateUrl: './clients.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./clients.component.css']
})

export class ClientsComponent{
    rows: Array<any>;

    constructor() {
        let btn = document.getElementById("coolbutton");
        if (btn === null) return;
        btn.addEventListener("click", (e: Event) => this.ClickMeButton());
    }

    ClickMeButton() {
        alert("toto");
    }
}
```

HTML file :

```
<input type="button" value="Click" id="coolbutton"/>
```

But an error is raised when the page loads :

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
NodeInvocationException: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: document is 
not defined
```

I am unable to find any explanations on how to import document in my TS componenet...

Comment: Rather that trying to access document in the component constructor, try using the [AfterViewInit](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#afterview) lifecycle hook.

Comment: Hi ! ty for the help, im gonna look into it right now !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just put the `(click)` on the element and call your function:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'clients',
    templateUrl: './clients.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./clients.component.css']
})

export class ClientsComponent{

    constructor() {}

    public clickMeButton(): void {
        alert("toto");
    }
}
```

`<input type="button" value="Click" (click)="clickMeButton()"/>`

Comment: even simpler. the after inits seems really powerfull but this is straight up what i wanted. TY !!

Comment: Quick question tho, the only modification was adding parenthesis around the click keyword in HTML, and the public modifier on the method (which is fine by me :). Where can i find a list of those event ? Let's say i want to do it on a text input and on the keyup event.

Comment: Hi, this is basically angular. i would suggest you read the official docs of angular: https://angular.io/. For a quick overview about angular event binding see this articel: https://coursetro.com/posts/code/59/Angular-4-Event-Binding